# How to get a button image into the Action bar

Tags: android, button, menu, android-actionbar

A button with a given image shall appear in the action bar. The Image below illustrates what I need: [image]

In order to isolate the problem, I used the template from Android Studio which has an action bar and added an item to the menu list pointing to my png file in the drawable resource folder.

Here the Code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.pm.pmactionbaricon;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

The menu Definition:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.pm.pmactionbaricon.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/distance_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/distance_waiting"
        android:title="@string/Distance"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

The main layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.pm.pmactionbaricon.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What I get from this is an Action bar without icon even though there is sufficient room:
[image]

The relevant menu item instead appears in the overflow menu:
[image]

Perhaps I have a fundamental misunderstanding about this. Any explanation would be welcome. Is it not possible to achieve this trivial task in Android? Which method do I have to apply to make a custom image visable as button and to control ist appearance and size in the action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom_toolbar.xml and include it in your layout.()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">


     //define your own layout here ,whatever you want to include

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />.In this way include it where you have  toolbar

Comment: Thanks a lot for supporting me. I have followed your advice. Now I have some progress and can define buttons with my png as background to appear in the toolbar in the same vertical position as my apps title (Icon Test). What I could not resolve is to get rid of the following phenomena: The actionbar has now the double height. Underneath my original Actionbar I have now an empty space. Do you have an explanation for this as well? Thanks Peter

Comment: Can you plesae share the image

Comment: Thanks for your help. I cannot add a file to a comment right? Since there is also more Information to share about this problem, I decided to describe it fully in a new case (39457616). The appearance of the button Image as such is now possible with your advice. So I think we can look at it as two types of problems (even though related). If you kindly look into 39457616, you might be able to help me. Thanks